# Não consigo obter retorno do webservice REST

Tags: jquery, ajax, front-end

Estou tentando uma comunicação do meu cliente .html com um serviço REST que criei em ASP.NET C#. A princípio era apenas para fazer login e caso o login e senha estivesse correto redirecionava para a pagina home da minha aplicação. O problema é o seguinte minha chamada AJAX só está executando com sucesso quando debugo o .js no navegador, caso o contrário é como se não tivesse ação nenhuma vinculada ao botão. Segue o código :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2196f3">
    <title>login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/framework7.material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/my-app.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Views -->
        <div class="views">
          <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
            <div class="view view-main">
                <div data-page="index" class="page">
                  <center><br><br><br><img src="img/logo_plantao_card.png"></center>
            <!-- Login -->
                    <form name= "dados">
                        <div class="list-block">
                            <ul>
                              <li class="item-content">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                  <div class="label cartao"><b>Cartão</b></div>
                                  <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="txt_cartao" id="txt_cartao" placeholder="Numero do Cartão"></input>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                              <li class="item-content">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                  <div class="label cartao"><b>Senha</b></div>
                                  <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="password" name="txt_senha" id="txt_senha" placeholder="Senha"></input>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                             </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p class="button-rows">
                            <input type="submit" id="btnEntrar" class="button button-big button-fill color-blue " value="Entrar" onclick="verifica_cartao()"></input>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Roda pé-->
                    <div class="rodape">
                    Copyright © 2016 BTI - Todos os direitos reservados
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/my-app.js"></script>
    <!--  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00="crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script> -->

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("click", "#btnEntrar", function(evt)
    {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:13383/api/cartao",
                    success: function (data) {
                    //window.open('home.html');
                    alert('ola');
                }
            });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Outras tentativa

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnEntrar", function(evt){
    //     $.ajax({
    //         type: "POST",
    //         url: "http://localhost:3687/api/cartao",
    //         data: {
    //             CodImp: '6064213000000001',
    //             senha: '1234'
    //         },
    //         dataType: "json",
    //         success: function (data) {
    //          alert("ola");
    //         },
    //         error: function (data) {
    //             alert("erro");
    //             //alert("Não foi possivel se conectar ");
    //         }
    //     });
    // });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3687/api/cartao",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
                CodImp: '6064213000000001',
                senha: '1234'
            },
      success: function (data) {
                alert("ola");
            },
      error: function(data){
        alert("erro");
      } 

    });
```

});

Comment: talvez esteja dando erro e ai não volta a resposta na chave sucess, tenta colocar a função para o erro;

Comment: Vc usa o chrome? Na aba network mostra se deu algum erro. Veja se tem algum retorno pelo chrome.

Comment: não apresenta erros, ja teste pelo chrome e o firefox

Comment: porem quando testo do postman o back end retorna sucess mas no ajax ele entra apenas no erro